# Bootstrap Mobile SubMenu Breaking top level Chrome/Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a page I'm working on currently: http://s.codepen.io/moletek/debug/QNeaXq And basically I think the sub-menu breaks when you open and close the parent item. The background will disappear, like it's closing both elements.

I've done some custom stuff, so you can view the src, but here is my standard html:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="stcs-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="first active"><a href="welcome" title="welcome" >Welcome</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown"><a href="about/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu"><li class="first"><a href="about/our-vision" title="Our Vision" >Our Vision</a></li>
          <li><a href="about/our-team" title="Our Team" >Our Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="about/church-plants" title="" >Plants</a></li>
         <li class="last"><a href="about/contact-us" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- A summary of the menu structure with submenu
```

You can reproduce this in the codepen mentioned above. Or view the GIF below So basically whenever you tap the dropdown parent, it will appear fine. But if you tap the parent again, the entire background will disappear when the child items do.

I'm quite baffled! I appreciate any help. 
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Checked it and working fine.

Comment: @CodeRomeos are you viewing in chrome or android device?

Comment: I checked it in Chrome.

Comment: Me too, no problems here: Chrome v50.0.2661.102 m

Comment: Please refer to the GIF i've added ^

I am on v51.0.2704.54 but also have seen this on mobile devices

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome.  Total no go in Firefox on a desktop, even though screen is adjusted small.  I can't get the menu to pull down at all.  And side note... style.css certainly has a lot of `!important` callouts.  I hate seeing those...

Comment: Now its working in Firefox.  There were no console errors, nothing appeared to be changing.  Way odd

Comment: @zipzit yeah we're using a bootstrap, so we have to overwrite a lot of it. I'm with you on that!